# nodejs - catch error at any deeper level

Tags: node.js, async-await, try-catch

How can I catch error thrown inside an `async` function. As in my example below:

I) Working example (Error catchable)

```
(async () => {
  try {
    // do some await functions

    throw new Error("error1")
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
})()
```

Console

```
Error: error1
    at __dirname (/home/test.js:25:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/quan/nodejs/IoT/test.js:30:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:201:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:626:3
```

II) But if I put `try-catch` outside of `async`, the exception becomes uncatchable, like below:

```
try {
  (async () => {
    throw new Error("error1")
  })()
}
catch(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

Console:

```
(node:3494) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: error1

(node:3494) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Is there a way to catch error thrown from `async` as demonstrated in II?

I have to ask this to simplify my code, which contains many `switch-case` and I don't want to handle `try-catch` in each `switch-case`.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can use promises to solve this problem, Add catch at end of the promise chain will help to catch the async errors.

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds(x) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            if(x === 'Error'){
                throw Error('My error')
            }

            setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(x);

          }, 2000);
        }).catch(function (e){
            console.log('error-------------------', e)
        });
      }

      async function add1(x) {
        const a = await resolveAfter2Seconds('success');
        const b = await resolveAfter2Seconds('Error');
        return x + a + b;
      }

      add1();
```